# Resize a Div by dragging its corners

Tags: javascript, function, event-handling, mouseevent

I want to create a drag option only at end-point or start-point of that div when clicked and dragged than it minimize or maximize.

I have this code upon this if we click anywhere in the div this saves that position and if we scroll back and forth from that position it changes the div
...

```
taskDurationEl.tabIndex = 0;
        var dragged = false
        var oldX = 0;
        taskDurationEl.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
            oldX = e.pageX;
            dragged = false
        })
        taskDurationEl.addEventListener('mousemove', function () {
            dragged = true
        })
        taskDurationEl.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
            if (dragged == true && e.pageX < oldX) {
                taskDurationElDragged = taskDurationEl;
                onTaskDurationDropSize(e);
            } else if (dragged == true && e.pageX > oldX) {
                taskDurationElDragged = taskDurationEl;
                onTaskDurationIncreaseSize(e);
            }
        })
```

This code changes the size by clicking anywhere inside that div

Only if we click at the ends of that tab the size of div changes and this is basically for a gantt chart

Comment: Please define "_end-point [and] start-point of div_". Top-left and bottom-right corners? All the borders? Something else?

Comment: Basically this is a span in gantt chart.
Applying the offset method all the values are 0 that why not able to define any end value for this